# How to match a PointerType in LLVM with certain type names?

Tags: exception, types, llvm

I want to capture an Instruction which is a throw instruction like:

```
 %12 = bitcast %java.security.cert.CertificateException* %11 to %java.lang.Throwable*, !dbg !201
```

I checked it is a BitCastInst first and get its destination type by:

```
llvm::Type* type = bitCastInst->getDestTy();
```

When I output the type by type->dump(), it shows:
%java.lang.Throwable*

How can I compare this type with "%java.lang.Throwable*"? I only found it lies in the subClass PointerType but there is no method like getName() to output a string for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Module::getTypeByName()`, passing "java.lang.Throwable" there, and then calling `->getPointerTo()`. This will give you a `Type*` to compare with. No need to compare names each time.